# BroadCast Receiver Error

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

Why is this not working? I have activityClass(`PlayListActivity.java`) and a serviceClass(`AudioService.java`). when I click on the `ListView`, the song should start playing but that's not is happening. When I click on the `ListView`, it closes the app with no error(such as `forced close`).

I got this error in LogCat:

Activity com.example.serviceaudio.PlayListActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.example.serviceaudio.PlayListActivity$AudioPlayerServiceConnection@41b1c448 that was originally bound here

FATAL EXCEPTION: manin
java.lang.RunTimeException: Error recieving broadcast Intent { act=com.example.serviceaudio.AudioService$AudioPlayerBroadCastResiever@41bdf88

Here are my codes:

PlayListActivity.java

```
 public class PlayListActivity extends ListActivity {

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new AudioPlayerServiceConnection();
private AudioService audioPlayer;
private Intent audioPlayerIntent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.playlist);

    audioPlayerIntent = new Intent(this, AudioService.class);
    bindService(audioPlayerIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    SongManager plm = new SongManager();
    this.songsList = plm.getPlayList(this);

    for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(i);
        songsListData.add(song);
    }// end loop

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, songsListData,
            R.layout.playlist_item, new String[] { "songTitle","songArtist"}, new int[] {
                    R.id.songTitle, R.id.songArtist });
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

        playSong(position);



        finish();

        }

    });
}

private final class AudioPlayerServiceConnection implements ServiceConnection {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder baBinder) {
        audioPlayer = ((AudioService.AudioPlayerBinder) baBinder).getService();
        startService(audioPlayerIntent);
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        audioPlayer = null;
    }
}

public void playSong(int songIndex){
    Intent intent = new Intent(AudioService.PLAY_SONG);
    intent.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);
    this.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

}
```

AudioService.java

```
public class AudioService extends Service implements OnCompletionListener{

public static final String PLAY_SONG_BASE = "com.example.serviceaudio.AudioService";
public static final String PLAY_SONG = PLAY_SONG_BASE + ".PLAY_SONG";
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String >> songList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
private SongManager songManager = new SongManager();
private MediaPlayer mp;
private AudioPlayerBroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new AudioPlayerBroadcastReceiver();

public int currentSongIndex;


public class AudioPlayerBinder extends Binder {
    public AudioService getService() {
        return AudioService.this;
    }
}

private final IBinder audioPlayerBinder = new AudioPlayerBinder();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return audioPlayerBinder;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(PLAY_SONG);
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);



}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    //release();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {

    stopSelf();
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

    private void release() {
        if( mp == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
        }
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }

//==== playSong() ========
    public void  playSong(int songIndex){
        // Play song

        songList = songManager.getPlayList(this);
        try {
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(songList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
            // Displaying Song title
            String songTitle = songList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");



        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }// == End of playSong() ===


private class AudioPlayerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        currentSongIndex = intent.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");


        if( PLAY_SONG.equals(action)) {
            playSong(currentSongIndex);
        } 

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely to be that you're binding to the `Service` but when you click on a list item, you're calling `finish()` which will terminate the `Activity`. There isn't anything in your code which shows you unbinding from the `Service`.

It seems you're confusing the issue by not only starting the `Service` but binding to it and also using a `BroadcastReceiver`. The purpose of binding to a `Service` is to allow direct communication between (for example) an `Activity` and the `Service` in which case, communicating via a `BroadcastReceiver` isn't necessary.

The most important aspect is if you bind to a `Service`, make sure you unbind from it in either `onPause()`, `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` depending on requirements.

Comment: what do you mean by communicating via a BroadcastReciever ins`t necessary?

Comment: Firstly, when you call `startService(...)` you pass it an `Intent` which could contain an 'extra' with the song path or URL etc. Also once a `Service` is bound the `Activity` can directly call the `Service` methods through the binder. I suggest you read this carefully... http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: I did what u say, I did `unbind` the `service` in `onDestroy()` but I git this error FATAL EXCEPTION : main

java.lang.RunTimeException: error recieveing broadcast Intent {act-com.exaple.serviceaudio.AudioService.PLAY_SONG flg=0x10 (has extras)} in com.example.serviceaudio.AudioService$AudioPlayerBroadcastReciever@41b4e818

Comment: Unregister the `BroadcastReceiver` in the `onDestroy()` method of the `Service` or get rid of it altogether and stop attempting to communicate with the `Service` using broadcasts and use the bound methods instead. Did you read that document I linked to?

Comment: Yes but I couldn`t understand it clearly. Can you give a code snippet base on my codes. tnx

Comment: I did unregister the `BroadcastReciever` in `onDestroy()` but now I go this error: 
Action not recognized: som.example.activityService.PLAY_SONG

java.lang.RunTimeException: error recieveing broadcast Intent {act-com.exaple.serviceaudio.AudioService.PLAY_SONG flg=0x10 (has extras)} in com.example.serviceaudio.AudioService$AudioPlayerBroadcastReciever@41b4e818